# How to make a space between them?

Tags: html, css

i try to make a footer menu, that is similar this site: pentlandfirth.com/de. when i mouse over the Link it has a background but it is on the dge of the border. How can i make a space between them? 
https://jsfiddle.net/13w3rmat/3/

```
    #fa{
  width: 600px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#fa ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}

#fa ul li{
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  padding-left: 3%;
  border-right: 1px solid #989;
}

#fa ul li:last-child{
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
}

#fa ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: #000;
}

    #fa ul li a:hover{
  color: #f00;
  background: gray;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding-right: 13px
```

}

```
              <div id="fa">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Test</a>
      <a href="#">Test</a>
      <a href="#">Test</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Test</a>
      <a href="#">Test</a>
      <a href="#">Test</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Test</a>
      <a href="#">Test</a>
      <a href="#">Test</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/p8p6ap93/1/)

Add a little `padding` in your `a` tag:

```
a {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

But preferably, give the `a`'s above a class and add the padding to that class.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `padding-bottom: 10px;` to  `padding: 5px;` in your `#fa ul li a{` css.

```
#fa ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px; //Here
  color: #000;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/13w3rmat/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

add `margin` & `padding` in your `a` tag

```
#fa{
  width: 600px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#fa ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}

#fa ul li{
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  padding-left: 3%;
  border-right: 1px solid #989;
}

#fa ul li:last-child{
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
}

#fa ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
  margin-right:30px;
}

#fa ul li a:hover{
  color: #f00;
  background: gray;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding-right: 13px
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/13w3rmat/4/

Answer (score 0):

```css
#fa ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px; /*use padding to the left here */
  color: #000;
}

/* Alternatively
================*/

#fa ul li a:hover{
  color: #f00;
  background: gray;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding-right: 13px; /*this line is missing a semi colon in yours*/
  padding-left: 10px;  /*use padding to the left here*/
}
```